# Resizing DIV depending on amount of characters in text field

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a text box, which i enter text into and it gets printed out in a div below as it is typed. Currently, the DIV can fit 24 characters into it and then i have the text to wrap. What i'm trying to do is to get the DIV to double in height for every 24 characters that are entered.

I want to do this using only Javascript and no jQuery

```
<div class="one">Input Some Text
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="pointlessInput"/>
            <script>
                var stringToBePrinted = document.getElementById("pointlessInput");
                var len = stringToBePrinted.length;

                stringToBePrinted.onkeyup = function(){
                    var len = stringToBePrinted.length;
                    document.getElementById("printbox").innerHTML = stringToBePrinted.value;
                    if(document.getElementById("pointlessInput").innerHTML.value.length == 24){
                        document.getElementById("printbox").style.height = "4em";
                    }
                }

            </script>
        </form>
        <div class="printbox" id="printbox"></div>
    </div>
```

stylesheet

```
.printbox {
border-width:thick 10px;
border-style: solid; 
background-color:#fff;
line-height: 2;
color:#6E6A6B;
font-size: 14pt;
text-align:center;
border: 3px solid #969293;
width:50%;
height:2em;
margin: auto;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var stringToBePrinted = document.getElementById("pointlessInput");

stringToBePrinted.onkeyup = function() {
  document.getElementById("printbox").innerHTML = stringToBePrinted.value;
  var multiple = Math.ceil(parseInt(document.getElementById("pointlessInput").value.length) / 24);
  document.getElementById("printbox").style.height = (multiple * 2) + "em";   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the if condition and the height from the css, it works just fine.
Check the below working example.

```js
var stringToBePrinted = document.getElementById("pointlessInput");
var len = stringToBePrinted.length;

stringToBePrinted.onkeyup = function(){
var len = stringToBePrinted.length;
document.getElementById("printbox").innerHTML = stringToBePrinted.value;
}
```

```css
.printbox {
border-width:thick 10px;
border-style: solid; 
background-color:#fff;
line-height: 2;

color:#6E6A6B;
font-size: 14pt;
text-align:center;
border: 3px solid #969293;
width:50%;
margin: auto;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">Input Some Text
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="pointlessInput"/>
            <script>
                
            </script>
        </form>
        <div class="printbox" id="printbox"></div>
    </div>
```